# How would I find the innerHTML index of text highlighted from textContent?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to program a simple text editor for fun.
I am stuck on this problem.
I want to add bold or italics to highlighted text on a button click.
I figure the best way to do this is get the index of the selected text and then add the bold tag / italic tag around the tag in the innerHTML.
However, I can not seem to get the position / index of the selected tag to carry over to the innerHTML. Obviosuly, the innerHTML code is offset by the tags.
Is there an easier way to do this?

I though finding the index of the highlighted text was the way to go. Okay. Unforunately, indexOf will only find the first occurance.

```js
var word_document = document.getElementById('word-document');


/* This code is for our bold button */
var bold_button = document.getElementById('bold-button')
bold_button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {


  /* Test to see if text is highlighted */
  let text = window.getSelection().toString();
  console.log("Selected Text: " + text);

  if (text.length > 0) {
      // Find the position of the highlighted text in the word document.
      let position = word_document.innerHTML.indexOf(text);  // Not a good way of doing it
      console.log("Pos: ", position);

      // Replace the highlighted text from the document with the bold text
      word_document.innerHTML.replace(text, "<b>" + text + "</b>");
  }
  /* If text is not highlighted, add a bold tag */
  else {
    // Add bold tag to bottom of document
    word_document.focus();
    word_document.innerHTML += "<b></b>";
    word_document.selectionEnd = word_document.innerHTML.length - 6;
  }
});

/* This code is for our italic button */
var italic_button = document.getElementById('italics-button');
italic_button.addEventListener('click', function() {

  let text = window.getSelection().toString();
   
   // Same issue

});
```

```html
<button id="bold-button">B</button>
<button id="italics-button">I</button>
<textarea id="word-document">Starting Text</textarea>
```

I suppose a possible way would be to iterate over the textContent and find if any text prior to the selected text matches it, and then set a variable to skip over that many matches. Is there an easier way to do this. Ideally, I would like to create a bold tag, or italic tag and append it to the textarea in a more proper fashion. I support traversing the DOM is probably a better way. Any ideas on how this might be more easily tackled?
Thanks

I use Plain / Vanilla Javascript.

Edit: Fixed code. Adding JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p1vek0ga/1/)

Comment: What is `word_document`?  Maybe you could make this a runnable snippet that illustrates your problem?

Comment: @wyck Oh my bad. I will do. Will add a jsfidddle

Comment: getRange() returns [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) object from which you can get selection start  and end. you don't have to using indexOf.

Comment: @Robert let me play with that and get back to you.

Comment: @Robert, this is similar to what I want to do. But I need to select the parentNode of that position:

Comment: Range.selectNode() - return node of selection. from it you can get parent. (if catch what you mean)

Comment: @Robert, I absolutely got you. I need to play with the code a bit, but I understand. Thanks!

Comment: i only add that you should get Range from your element not window. because then this bold button will work for all elements on page, like menu items.

Comment: @Robert, I follow I can not quite seem to get it. I figure I want: 1) A Range or Selection from the word_document with text of the selectionStart or selectionEnd.  2) Get the parent Node of that Range or Selection. Is that correct in thinking?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```html
<html>
<header>
</header>
<body>
    <button id="bold-button" onClick="makeBold()">B</button>
    <div id="word-document" contenteditable>Starting Text</div>
    <script>
        function makeBold() {
            var inputText = document.getElementById("word-document");
            var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML;
            text = window.getSelection().toString();
            var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
            if (index >= 0) { 
                    innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0,index) + "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>" + innerHTML.substring(index,index+text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
                        inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML;
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

the idea here is to use a fake textArea: div with content editable.
I hope it helps u,

Good Luck!

Comment: I do not use jQuery and execCommand has been depreciated.

Comment: So if you are not using jQuery, try my second suggestion, i just edited my post, it may gives u a hint. Good luck amigo.

Comment: i guess this solution will not work if the selected text occurs multiple times in innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

simple dummy solution. this don't work for nested tags.

I highly recommended to read this [tutorial](https://javascript.info/selection-range)

```js
 function action({tag, classes}, event){
    const text = document.getElementById("word-document");
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    const before = text.innerHTML.substr(0, range.startOffset);
    const after = text.innerHTML.substr(range.endOffset);
    const selected = text.innerHTML.substr(range.startOffset,range.endOffset - range.startOffset );

    const warpped = `<${tag} ${classes ? "class=" + classes : ""}>${selected}</${tag}>`
    text.innerHTML = before + warpped + after;
  }
```

```css
#word-document {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.underline{
  text-decoration-line: underline;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="action({tag: 'b'})">B</button>
<button onclick="action({tag: 'i'})">I</button>
<button onclick="action({tag: 'span', classes:'underline'})">Under score</button>
<div id="word-document" contenteditable>Starting Text</div>
```

Comment: I actually was just reading that tutorial ;)

Comment: @DavidFrick so the tricky part will be catch in what tag selection start startContainer and ends in endContainer.  And then proper close and open tag to avoid tag mismatching

Comment: So lets take this javascript: ``` function action({tag, classes}, event) {
   // Get Text document
    let text = document.getElementById("word-document");
    
    var start = text.selectionStart;
    // obtain the index of the last selected character
    var finish = text.selectionEnd;
    // obtain the selected text
    var sel = text.value.substring(start, finish);
    // do something with the selected content
    console.log(sel.parentNode);
  }
  ``` Since I am on, I have to do it this way. Unfortunately it also is with a  textarea versus a div that is contenteditable since

Comment: Firefox does not like that

Comment: you can't have nested tags within textarea.... this is why contenteditable. and firefox can have many selected ranges chrome not' so different behavior can comes from this difference

Comment: I see what you said. So what I have selects the parent of the highlighted text. I will then need to replace the innerHTML I guess. Still working on that.

Comment: selected parrent is in commonAncestorContainer

Comment: i think that you have to place b tag in current start Container from start to end of this container. The same on the end you have to put tag in endContainter in selected range and then wrapped everything between this tag in one big tag. But im not shure that this will correct for all types of tags.  Some of tags like p can't have block tags like div nested within it